# copying the elements of a list to another list with a condition in python

Tags: python

I have a list, say `list_1 = [5,12,22,37,65,100]`, now I want to copy the elements of this list to another list say `list_2` which will also have the same number of elements, i.e in this case = 6. I just want to run a loop for 6 times and generate 6 different random numbers and depending on the values of random numbers I want a take an element from `list_1` and copy that to `list_2` using the below logic (For the generated random number take the next higher number from the list):

```
x=(random.randint(1, 100))
print(f"Generated random number: {x}")
list_1=[5,12,22,37,65,100]
for i in list_1:
    if i>x:
        print(i)
        break
```

But the catch is one number is not allowed more than `n/2` times. In this case, no number can come from `list_1` more than 3 times. If the 1st 3 generated random numbers are : 55, 61 and 58 then the first 3 elements of `list_2` will be = [65,65,65], so 65 can't be copied anymore. In that case I wanted to use the logic as :

```
from random import choice
print(choice([i for i in range(1,100) if i not in range(37,65)]))
```

But unable to get the proper and desired output. Please help.

Comment: could you please provide expected inpts and outputs.

Comment: @HarshaBiyani , input: `[5,12,22,37,65,100]`, and output will vary depending upon the generated random numbers. `[100,100,65,100,37,12]` this can be one output , `[12,100,65,65,37,65]` this can be another output and so on.

Comment: Is it correct that there is an outer loop missing that steps through six random numbers?

Comment: Your number choice if you reach the n/2 limit, is unclear: do you want *any* number that is *not* interval between the lower and upper "limit" of the original `x`, even if that random number is not in `list_1`?

Comment: @9769953 yes absolutely. I was just checking in that part how things were working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

General solution:

```py
import random
from random import choice

list_1 = [5,12,22,37,65,100]
list_2 = []

n_items = len(list_1)

for _ in range(n_items):
    rand_number = random.randint(1, 100)
    print(f"Generated random number: {rand_number}")

    for i, number in enumerate(list_1):
        if number > rand_number:
            n_same_numbers_in_list2 = sum(l2i == number for l2i in list_2)

            if (n_same_numbers_in_list2+1) <= n_items/2:
                number_to_append = number
            else:
                lower_bound = list_1[i-1] if i > 0 else 0
                upper_bound = number
                number_to_append = choice([i for i in range(1,100) if i not in range(lower_bound,upper_bound)])
            list_2.append(number_to_append)
            break

print(list_2)
```

We declare the two lists and enter a n_items x loop. We generate a random number and get the 1st number (`number`) greater than our generated random number. We count how many times we have seen this number previously and store it in `n_same_numbers_in_list2`. We check that "If we were to add this `number` to `list_2` as well, would that be greater than `n_items/2`?". If not, we want to append `number`, else, we want to choose a random number in the range [1, 100] NOT in the range `number` and the number lesser than `number` from `list_1` (if that exists, otherwise 0).

We can simplify a little by pre-generating the random list and only using a single `for` loop. We can also keep generating `number_to_append` until we get a number outside of the invalid range:

```py
import random

list_1 = [5,12,22,37,65,100]
random_numbers = [random.randint(1, 100) for _ in list_1]
list_2 = []

n_items = len(list_1)

for i, (number, rand_number) in enumerate(zip(list_1, random_numbers)):
    if number > rand_number:
        n_same_numbers_in_list2 = sum(l2i == number for l2i in list_2)

        if (n_same_numbers_in_list2+1) <= n_items/2:
            number_to_append = number
        else:
            lower_bound = list_1[i-1] if i > 0 else 0
            upper_bound = number
            number_to_append = random.randint(1, 100)
            while number_to_append in range(lower_bound,upper_bound):
                number_to_append = random.randint(1, 100)
        list_2.append(number_to_append)
        break

print("Random number:", random_numbers)
print("List2", list_2)
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation to your answer.

Comment: Hey @Zoom whenever there is a number coming more than 'n/2' times then your `number_to_append = choice([i for i in range(1,100) if i not in range(lower_bound,upper_bound)])` this condition does not make sure that the elements which will come belongs to the 'list_1'. I mean I am getting `[100, 100, 100, 39, 65, 22]` this as one output where the 1st 4 random numbers generated were `84,75,90,82` so for 82 as it can't print 100 anymore, it is printing 39 which is not in the `list_1`.

Comment: Hi @Dev, that was not listed as a requirement in the original question. What is the desired outcome? A random number from the list that is not 100? Does the number need to follow any other rule?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why choosing random number from 0 to 100 when you just want to chose random number from the list it self? Use `random.choice` to chose randomly from a list.

Here's an smaller and simpler method

```
from random import choice
a=[5,12,22,37,65,100]
c=a.copy()
b=[]
for i in range(len(a)):
    num=choice(c)
    if b.count(num)>=(len(a)/2):
        c.remove(num)
        num=choice(c)
    else:
        
        b.append(num)
print(b)
```

Explantion:

1. Took a copy of `a` in variable `c` using `copy()` function.
2. Chose a number from the list `c`, and also checked if that particular number has been appended to the list `b` `n\2` times.
3. If it's True, then removed that particular number from list `c` and again chose a random number. (*So that the number wont be repeated further*)
4. If it's False then appended that number in list `b`.

Comment: The probability distribution will be different if we choose an element on random compared to if we select the next number greater than a random number in the [1, 100] interval.

Comment: @Zoom Absolutely correct!